# How do I get the text in an alert/prompt/dialog in perl with selenium webdriver?

Tags: perl, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, alert

I want to get a string in the picture below. It is inside of an alert, prompt or dialog. My code is written in Perl and I am using Selenium Webdriver to navigate through the page.

[image: Image shows the alert and the Url I want from it]

**What I have achieved so far:**

- finding the link with selenium and clicking on it
- waiting for the alert to appear
- get a string from the alert, but not the string in the text field

**Code**

```
my $copy_elem = wait_until {      
    $d->find_element_by_id('clipboard-link'); 
};        
$copy_elem->click;

select undef, undef, undef, 8.00;

my $alert = wait_until {
  $d->get_alert_text;
};
```

`$alert` output is "Copy Link"

So the text that I want is inside the alert's text field. With get_alert_text I only get the Alert string, but not the text field content. I searched the Web for answers and saw people using window handles to switch to the alert. I tried to look for similar functions in Selenium Webdriver's documentation:

[CPAN Selenium Webdriver Docu with list of functions](http://search.cpan.org/~aivaturi/Selenium-Remote-Driver-0.15/lib/Selenium/Remote/Driver.pm)

I tried getting the window handles and load them into an array, but it does not get a second window handle for the alert. get_current_window_handle doesn't work either. I used phantomjs and chrome as browsers. As far as I know there is no `driver.switchto().alert();` for perl.

Comment: Your second link is broken. It contains the same image as the first one.

Comment: oh thanks I will change it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to override the [prompt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt) function in the page with a script injection:

```
# override the prompt function
$d->execute_script('window.prompt=function(message, input){window.last_prompt = {message: message, input: input}};');

# trigger a prompt
select undef, undef, undef, 8.00;

# get the prompt default input
my $input = $d->execute_script('return window.last_prompt.input;');
```

Comment: Your Solution worked! I just copy&pasted and moved the click between the script executions.